# 98 accord v6 rough idle car stall

Tags: honda, electrical, accord

I blew my heater hose on my 98 Honda Accord v6 vtech sprayed coolant all over my cap and wires so I replaced the wires and my idle was fluctuating so I then cleaned my iacv as I was coming to a stop the car stalled out and wouldn't start so I wiggles the spark plug wires and it fired up what else could it be

Answer (score 1):

If you wiggled the wires and it restarted, I'd suggest you ensure all of the wires are firmly in place on the cap and on the spark plugs. Since it wouldn't actually start, you should pay close attention to the coil wire. If it were the spark plug wires it would probably start, but would run rough. Seeing as how it would not start at all, this might point to the coil wire, which would preclude spark from getting to any of the spark plugs and not allowing it to start.